# Monotonically increasing Riemann sums for monmials

Tags: sequences-and-series

For an integer $r\ge1$, consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n\ge2}$ defined by
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^{r+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^r$$
It is easy to prove, for $r=1,2,3$, that this sequence in increasing using the known closed form of the sum.

But is it true in general that for any integer $r\ge1$ this sequence is increasing?

In fact, it can be proved that this is true starting from a certain index $n_0$ that depends on $r$, and numerical evidence suggests that the answer is yes, but I could not find a proof, Any help?

Comment: Proving $a_n$ is increasing is *equivalent* to prove that $$a_n\le \frac{n^r}{(n+1)^{r+1}-n^{r+1}}$$ I don't know if it helps. Very happy to see you @Omran Kouba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general result holds (see Theorem 4 in [Monotonicity of Certain Riemann Sums](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/riemann.pdf) by D. Borwein, J. Borwein and B. Sims).

> If  the  function $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$
>   is  concave  on  the  interval $[0,c]$, convex
>   on $[c,1]$ and  increasing  on $[0,1]$
>   then
>   $$\sigma_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k/n)$$
>   is an increasing sequence, and
>   $$\tau_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n)$$
>   is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Good catch! (+1)

Comment: Great, Thank you, this is what I was looking for. (+1)

Comment: @Omran Kouba You are welcome. Have a nice day.